# Quero usar o Web sql mas não estou conseguindo criar tabela nem inserir informações nela

Tags: javascript, sql, html5, aplicação-web, websql

```
let db = openDatabase('produto_teste','1.0','banco de dados para cadastro do produto',2*1024*1024);
db.transaction(function(tx){
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT referencia(\
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,\
    nome VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    marca VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    categoria VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    template VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    grade INTEGER NOT NULL\
  );',[[]],null,null);
})
```

Esse é o meu código de conexão, ele cria o banco mas não esta criando a tabela, o que pode ser?A forma que estou fazendo esta errado? 
Quando abro as ferramentas de desenvolvedor e vou para aplicações eu encontro o banco q criei mas não existe as tabelas

Comment: Desculpem, se não for pedir muito, alguém poderia explicar por a necessidade das barras invertidas antes dos campos da tabela e destes dois itens no final +++ ;',[], null, null); Não estava conseguindo mas agora deu certo, só não entendi o porque...

Comment: @VitorPaulon no ECMAScript (acho que 2015 em diante) a barra dentro de uma string significa que ela continua em outra linha. Acho má idéia usar, pois qualquer espaço depois da barra invalida a linha, provavelmente é preferivel fechar a string com aspas e na linha seguinte continuar com `+`, veja aqui: https://ideone.com/bexFrP - Uma possível exceção para justificar a barra talvez fosse uma continuação de regex e não de string, mas eu evitaria também - E sobre o resto do que perguntou, precisa abrir o manual da função executeSql, que os parâmetros estão descritos lá.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando estiver trabalhando com `WebSql` e ocorrer um erro, adicione um `callback` no retorno do erro ao chamar o `transaction.executeSql`.:

```
let db = openDatabase('produto_teste','1.0','banco de dados para cadastro do produto',2*1024*1024);
db.transaction(function(tx){
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT referencia(\
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,\
    nome VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    marca VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    categoria VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    template VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    grade INTEGER NOT NULL\
  );',[[]],null, function (t, e) { console.error(e); });
})
```

ao fazer isto, teria visto o seguinte

```
SQLError {code: 5, message: "could not prepare statement (1 near "referencia": syntax error)"}
SQLError {code: 5, message: "could not prepare statement (1 near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error)"}
SQLError {code: 5, message: "number of '?'s in statement string does not match argument count"}
```

Então se resolvemos estes problemas, teremos o seguinte script.:

```
let db = openDatabase('produto_teste','1.0','banco de dados para cadastro do produto',2*1024*1024);
db.transaction(function(tx){
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS referencia(\
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\
    nome VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    marca VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    categoria VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    template VARCHAR NOT NULL,\
    grade INTEGER NOT NULL\
  );',[], null, null);
})
```

Mas tente se atentar à um detalhe, o `WebSQL` não tem um bom suporte `CrossBrowser`, o seu código não vai funcionar no `IE` e `Firefox`.

te aconselho a utilizar o [`LocalDB.js`](http://agnostic.github.io/LocalDB.js/) no lugar do `WebSQL`

Comment: Amigão o IndexedDb vc acha uma boa opção?

Comment: Muito Obrigado Pela Ajuda!

Comment: @Estevoliveira o IndexedDB também vai sofrer com o problema de compatibilidade, te aconselho à utilizar alguma micro library que abstraia isto, como o LocalDB citado na resposta, ele vai usar o WebSQL se disponível, se não o IndexedDB, por fim vai usar o localStorage ou sessionStorage

Comment: Blz. Obrigado pela dica.